# Regex delimit the start of a string and the end

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm been having trouble with regex, which I doesn't understand at all.

I have a string '#anything#that#i#say' and want that the regex detect one word per #, so it will be [#anything, #that, #i, #say].
Need to work with spaces too :(

The closest that I came is [#\w]+, but this only get 1 word and I want separated.

Comment: Mostra teu código completo

Comment: you mean spaces before and after '#' sign! right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close; `[#\w]` will match anything that is either a `#` or a word character. But what you want is to match a single `#` followed by any number of word characters, like this: [`#\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/5eqH9j/2) without the brackets

```js
var str = "#anything#that#i#say";
var regexp = /#\w+/gi;
console.log(str.match(regexp));
```

It's possible to have this deal with spaces as well, but I'd need to see an example of what you mean to tell you how; there are lots of ways that "need to work with spaces" can be interpreted, and I'd rather not guess.

Comment: Ohh yes, what I mean with spaces is the spaces between hashtags like "# anything #that" i need this to be only two words, without taking the space between.
But your answer already made that.
Thanks :) and sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 0):

```
use expression >>  /#\s*(\w+)/g
```

\s* : to check if zero or more spaces you have between # and word

This will match 4 word in your string '#anything#that#i#say'
even your string is containing space between '#anything# that#i#  say'

sample to check: http://www.regextester.com/?fam=97638